# Single branch with multiple PRs

Tags: git, github

I've started a branch from master `git checkout me/feature`, and feature is a feature that needs to be reviewed and merged back into master.

While developing feature it is clear that I need to update a component (so feature is dependent on component, more specifically the updated component), and that component will need to be reviewed with a PR and merged into dev on a remote. It will take some time to review the component, and I will need to continue to work on the feature while the component is in review.

So I am half way through developing the feature, which depends upon changes that will need to be a separate branch and PR for the component (which will be a branch `me/component`).

I only have untracked files at the moment, what is my best strategy in order to:

1. Commit my current work locally so everything is not untracked
2. Branch off only some files into `me/component`, and create a PR when the component is finished
3. Keep `me/feature` in sync with `me/component` as the feature depends on the component.
4. Be able to work on `me/feature` even before `me/component` is reviewed and merged into `dev`

Comment: It isn't clear (at least to me) what the dependencies are here.  Is `feature` dependent on `component` in any way?  Is `component` dependent on `feature`?

Comment: Feature is dependent on a component.

Comment: Stash or commit your current feature work, checkout a new branch for the component, complete it, issue the PR, merge it, then return to the feature again.

Comment: But I'm going to need to continue to work on the feature before the component has been reviewed and merged.

Comment: Then change branches and do that.

Comment: How can I keep the feature branch me/feature in sync with the component branch me/component - as soon as I branch I've lost the dependency.

Comment: You can have 2 branches (`me/feature` and `component`). Whenever you push to `component`, `pull` (`merge`) those commits to `me/feature`. When you finish `me/feature` (after `component` have been merged into `master` and into `me/feature`), your changes in `component` already in `me/feature` and `master` will not conflict.